# Onchange event with AngularStrap select element

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-strap

I want to execute a function when the value of the select element changes (the select element in angular-strap is html  tag)
My HTML:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="selectedCriteria" data-html="1" ng-options="choice.value as choice.label for choice in selectChoices" bs-select>
      Action <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
```

My JS:

```
$scope.selectedCriteria = "Location";
$scope.selectChoices = [{'value':'Location','label':'<i class=\'fa fa-map-marker\'></i> Location'},
{'value':'Age','label':'<i class=\'fa fa-male\'></i> Age'}];
```

I tried putting an ng-click directive with a function in the controller but it captures the value of the current selected value on click not when the element changes

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of options one is using `ngChange` [Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

The other is using `$watch`.  See the $watch section of the [`scope`api reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

**An example using `watch`** *(this would be in your controller)*

```
$scope.$watch('selectedCriteria', function() {
     $scope.SomeFunction();
});
```

**An example using `ngChange`**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
   ng-change="SomeFunction()"
   ng-model="selectedCriteria" data-html="1" 
   ng-options="choice.value as choice.label for choice in selectChoices" bs-select>
      Action <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```